# Java OpenOffice UNO API: How to scale spreadsheet document?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I have an Excel document and I want to export it to PDF format. However, my document goes beyond A4 format area and I want to scale it before export.

Some body knows any solution of this problem?

1. How i can scale excel document before pdf export?
2. Does Open Office UNO api allows such operation as 'fit width'?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried selecting `Open Office Calc` -> `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Open Office Calc` -> `General` -> `Use printer metrics for text formatting` ?